# How to install scala on Heroku?

Tags: bash, scala, heroku, playframework, sbt

I want to use a [scala script](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166) in console on Heroku. 
So, after command

```
$heroku run bash
```

I try a script `./scala_script.sh`, but the result is `scala: not found`.
So, how to install scala or even some package on Heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If this is a Scala app, you should use the [Scala buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala). You can hardcode the buildpack url:

```
$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala
```

If you need Scala in addition to Play! Framework, you can experiment with [buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to get both buildpacks applied to your app.

Comment: Ok, but what have to be written at the head of `scala_script.sh` (like `exec scala ...`) so the last one to be executable?

Comment: If you get scala in with your app, it should by fine because `scala` is going to be in the PATH.

Comment: It looks like I'm missing something, since I couldn't find `scala` in PATH, only `sbt`.